# How to get the most recent child entity in an efficient way?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following EF entities:

```
public class Worker {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
}

public class Exam {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
  public Int32 BPSystolic { get; set; }
  public Int32 BPDiastolic { get; set; }
  public virtual Worker Worker { get; set; }
}
```

I need to select the BPSystolic and BPDiastolic of the most recent exam of each worker.

Then I need to make some calculations with it ... So I started my Query as:

```
context.Workers          
  .GroupBy(x => x.Worker)
  .Select(x => 
    x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Created)
    .Select(y => new { 
      BPDiastolic = y.BPDiastolic, 
      BPSystolic = y.BPSystolic }
   ).FirstOrDefault())
  .Select(z => // Calculations here)
  .ToList()
```

Do you think this has a good performance? It feels strange to me ...

Maybe using SelectMany would be a better approach?

How should I create this query?

Answer (score 0):

another approach for example:

```
from
    e in (
        from
            p in Exams
        select  new { 
            o = (p.CreatedDate.Value.Year * 10000 + 
                 p.CreatedDate.Value.Month * 100 +  
                 p.CreatedDate.Value.Day).ToString() + 
                 "-" + p.BPSystolic.ToString() + 
                 "-" + p.BPDiastolic.ToString(), 
            w = p.Worker.Id }
    ) group e by e.w into g
select 
    new {
        n = g.Key,
        m = g.Max(x => x.o)
    }
```

you should get the last exam for every worker. The exam is serialized as a string. So you have to unserialize it.

Now you should compare execution plan or you should test for perfs at sql server level.

PS:

- as I haven't your context I can't fully test, but it works on a single table.
- EF6.